# SharePoint 2010 - Prevent Site Collection from being crawled by Google

Tags: site-collection

From the SharePoint Ribbon, for SharePoint 2010, how do we prevent a new blank site from being crawled by Google or any public search engines on the web?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two ways to tell the robots to not crawl your site:

1. Adding robots.txt with the following content in the root folder with SharePoint Designer (All Items in SPD)

   ```
   User-agent: *
   Disallow: /
   ```

[image]

2. Adding meta tag in your master page's Head section as below should prevent the robots from crowling you site.

   ```
   <meta name="robots" content="noindex" >
   ```

I haven't tested it does evey robot out there respects this meta tag setting or not.

It's also posible to prevent only Googlebot from crowling your site as follows

```
 <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

Check this article from google
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?rd=1

Comment: thank you Naim for the rich feedback!  But where is the "All Items" folder under my new blank site in SharePoint Designer?  I don't see a folder called that...or did mean to just place the robots.txt file in the root directory of that specific site collection?  thanks!

Comment: Yes, when you open a site with SharePoint Designer on the Site Objects you'll see All Items. Just drag and drop the file there. I updated my answer.